# SFINAE enable_if for variadic perfect forwarding template on reference/pointer const-ness

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

I want to create a variadic perfect-forwarding `make_shared<T>` wrapper, but one which is SFINAEd on whether the constructor of `T` takes any non-const reference/pointer arguments.  The idea is to have two wrappers, called `construct` and `construct_nonconst`, where when constructing a `Foo(int& r)` or `Foo(int* r)`, one is obliged to use the latter.  The purpose of this is so that when developers write classes whose constructors require non-const parameters, they can do so, but it clearly shows up at the call site that the construction may have local side-effects.

I looked at [Implementing variadic type traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687026/implementing-variadic-type-traits), and played with `is_constructible` (I was trying to convert my Args... parameter pack to all the `const` versions therein), but I can't quite seem to figure it out.

Desired outcome:

```
struct NonConst
{
  NonConst(int& uhOh)
  {
    uhOh = 2;
  }
};

struct Const
{
  Const(const int& noProblemo)
  {
    // ...
  }
};

struct ByValueStr
{
  ByValueStr(std::string noProblemo)
  {
    // ...
  }
};

int x = 5;
const int y = 5;
std::string s("foo")

auto nc1 = builder<NonConst>::construct(x); // this doesn't compile
auto nc2 = builder<NonConst>::construct_nonconst(x); // fine, but noticeable
auto c1 = builder<Const>::construct(x); // fine
auto c2 = builder<ByValueStr>::construct(s); // fine
```

Comment: I wonder if this is really a good idea. A constructor might not use the pointer or reference to modify the referent, but a member function could modify it later. In that case you needlessly force people to write `construct_nonconst`. Unless it's intentional in this case too?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that 99% of all the classes will be immutable and/or referential transparent and it should be very clear when this is not the case.

Comment: I should also add that I tried doing this with just variadic `const Args&... ` but ran into problems with constructors taking strings using char literals.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add const to all lvalue arguments?

Comment: I am not sure, I tried to add const to my Args... while using `is_constructible` but it didn't appear to do anything. Maybe I am misunderstanding. Universal reference with perfect forwarding is perfect, I just want to turn it off if there are any non-const pointers or references (or smart pointers for that matter)

Comment: I meant: `template<class T> T const& const_if_lvalue(T& t) { return t; } template<class T> T&& const_if_lvalue(T&& t) { return move(t); } template<typename R, typename... Args> R construct(Args&&... args) { return R(const_if_lvalue(forward<Args>(args))...); }`

Comment: @dyp, that seems to work but only if I add an enable_if to the otherwise universal reference implementation of `const_if_lvalue`, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748104/preventing-non-const-lvalues-from-resolving-to-rvalue-reference-instead-of-const , `template< class T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<T>::value>::type >
T&&
const_if_lvalue(T&& t)
{
  return std::move(t);
}`

Comment: If you'd like to write that up as an answer, it works for me.

Comment: @experquisite Did you use `template<class T> T const& const_if_lvalue(T const& t) { return t; }`? It is important that the function parameter is `T&`, not `T const&`. Which compiler did you use?

Comment: I used `T& t` but got ambiguous overload errors in gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: @experquisite Interesting. Looks like a bug: it works in gcc 4.9 -- You can as well write it up yourself as an answer, and maybe explain how this helps you. I don't think I've understood your original issue entirely.